# What is the probability of spinning a roulette wheel that has four colors (Red,Blue,Green and Yellow) and landing on the color red two times in a row?

Tags: probability

What is the probability of spinning a wheel that has four colors (Red,Blue,Green and Yellow) and landing on the color red two times in a row?

Answer (score 1):

What is the probability you get red with a single roll. $\frac{1}{4}$

Suppose you allready had the luck of getting red (this happens $\frac{1}{4}$'th of the times.)

Then the odds you roll it again is $\frac{1}{4}$ (so this happens $\frac{1}{4}$'th of $\frac{1}{4}$'th of the times.)

So it happens $\frac{1}{16}$'th of the times. In other words the probability is $\frac{1}{16}$

Comment: glad to help you.

Comment: How do you change the fraction into a percent ?

Comment: You do $\frac{100}{16}=6.25$. So it's $6.25\%$